# Bad query - INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a bunch of undefinded index warnings when i print out my data from a SQL query, when i remove the INNER JOINS most of the warnings disappear. I am not sure what is causing that error.

My code is here:

```
<?php
    $id      = $_GET['id'];
    $sql     = "SELECT * FROM updates INNER JOIN clients ON updates.c_id = clients.c_id INNER JOIN pages ON updates.page = pages.p_id INNER JOIN projects ON updates.p_id = projects.p_id WHERE u_id='$id' LIMIT 1";
    echo $sql;
    $result  = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row     = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    // put update_id in hidden form and pass it to the next page
    $u_id = $row['u_id'];
?>
<h4>Viewing update for <i><? echo $row['fname'] ." ". $row['lname']  ?></i> for their <i><a href="<? echo $row['p_url']; ?>" title="View <? echo $row['p_title']; ?>"><? echo $row['p_title']; ?></a> project</i></h4>
<h4><b>Posted on: </b> <? echo $row['date_submitted'] = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); ?></h4>
```

Any idea on what I can do? The reason I have the INNER JOIN for CLIENTS is because "fname" and "lname" are stored there

```
clients.c_id = updates.c_id
```

Where I have: "p_url" "p_title" those are stored in the table PROJECTS which is also:

```
clients.c_id = projects.c_id
```

---

#### Edit with new problem

My code is here:

```
$sql     = "SELECT 
    updates.u_id AS u_id,
    updates.date_submitted AS date_submitted,
    updates.deadline AS deadline,
    updates.description AS description,
    updates.priority AS priority,
    pages.page_name AS page_name,
    clients.fname AS fname,
    clients.lname AS lname,
    projects.p_url AS p_url,
    projects.p_title AS p_title,
    FROM updates INNER JOIN clients ON updates.c_id = clients.c_id INNER JOIN pages ON updates.page = pages.p_id INNER JOIN projects ON updates.p_id = projects.p_id WHERE u_id='$id' LIMIT 1";
```

The error is:

> Not unique table/alias: 'clients'

Comment: What exactly are the warnings you're getting?

Comment: Please, when you post questions make your code as small/readable as possible. Most part of your code is irrelevant and unreadable.

Comment: Undefined Index when displaying my $row array.

@presario - I edited my code, i made it smaller..i will keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: Hmm, I'll edit information into the bottom of my answer as you change this, I suppose. Not sure of a better way to do it.

Comment: Please revert this to the original question to make the answers make sense! The new error is a trivial misplaced comma, which is much less interesting.

Comment: There, I combined the problems, I agree it's not a good idea to change a question to something else entirely after people have already answered.

Answer (score 2):

Edited answer:

Ah, I incorrectly assumed it had to do with SQL indexes. It appears it's actually a PHP error, related to you trying to print out array elements that don't exist.

For all of your prints that include elements of `$row` (`$row['deadline']`, etc), you need to make sure that there are actually columns named that being returned by your query. If there's not a column named "deadline", that attempt to print it is going to generate the warning.

---

**Edit again**: since this got bumped up, I guess I'll go into a little more detail.

First of all, as bobince points out, you have SQL injection possible. The first line should be:

```
$id      = intval($_GET['id']);
```

if $id will always be an integer, and `mysql_real_escape_string()` if it could be a string.

Second, `SELECT *` is generally bad form, especially in a case with joins. I don't know exactly which tables particular fields come from, but your query should look more like this, where you select only the fields you're actually going to use:

```
$sql = "SELECT clients.fname, clients.lname, projects.p_url, projects.p_title, updates.date_submitted ".
        "FROM updates ".
            "INNER JOIN clients ON updates.c_id = clients.c_id ".
            "INNER JOIN pages ON updates.page = pages.p_id ".
            "INNER JOIN projects ON updates.p_id = projects.p_id ".
        "WHERE updates.u_id='$id' ".
        "LIMIT 1";
```

Next, `$u_id` gets set to exactly the same value as `$id` already had, so it's kind of a pointless variable.

Finally, on the last line, you have:

```
<? echo $row['date_submitted'] = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); ?>
```

I'm not sure what you're expecting this to do, but it's going to assign `date("F j, Y, g:i a");` to `$row['date_submitted']` and then end up printing out "true" or "1" or something, that's probably not what you were going for.

---

**Newest problem:** You both try to select from clients, and join clients, you can't do both, at least without giving one of them an alias.

Comment: I did make sure of that. There is data in my columns.

Comment: The columns in projects table are actually named, literally, "p_url" and "p_title"? This seems out of form because updates doesn't have "u_date_submitted" and clients doesn't have "c_fname" and "c_lname".

Comment: Thank you for going in depth. I will keep all of this in mind for next time. I updated my error above where the older one was. 


Thanks,

RYan

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with the SQL (but I could be wrong).  You might take a look at [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,126269,126415#msg-126415) thread for a start.

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT * FROM updates INNER JOIN clients

When you ‘SELECT *’ you get each column from both tables. Because columns can have the same names, the column names generated automatically by ‘*’ are prefixed with the table name. So your associative array will contain indexes like:

```
updates.u_id
clients.c_id
...
```

So when you try to access the array using an unprefixed column name such as 'page_name', it fails because that index isn't there.

You can use the full column name ('pages.page_name'), or you can explicitly give your own column names by saying:

```
SELECT updates.u_id AS u_id, pages.page_name AS page_name, ...
FROM updates JOIN client ...
```

> u_id='$id'

Whoops, SQL injection hole. Congratulations, you are this week's 1000th winner of the [obligatory xkcd link](http://xkcd.com/327/).

mysql_real_escape_string() is your friend. (Even better: mysqli parameterised queries.)

> <? echo $row['deadline']; ?>

Whoops, HTML injection hole. htmlspecialchars() is your friend.

Comment: Hey,

So where i have my rows printing I should have:

echo htmlspecialchars($row['deadline']);

Like so?

Comment: Hey, In my first post I updated my SQL and I get an error. I think I need to edit the FROM clause now. Am i correct? Would I just list the table names there? I will give that a shot.

Ryan

Comment: echo htmlspecialchars: yes. It's also possible to write a wrapper function that just calls echo htmlspecialchars, with a much shorter name like h(), to save yourself some typing.

Comment: New error: you have a trailing ‘,’ after “projects.p_title AS p_title”.

Comment: Hey, thank you! I have this for catching data being sent from forms: http://pastie.org/422657 - does that look fine?

Also, i removed that trailing , and I get:

Not unique table/alias: 'clients'